# Can Someone Explain how these bootstrap classes work

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to understand how these classes are making four columns on larger screens and one column on mobile. And how can i make it two columns on mobile screens. I read the documentation but it still doesnt make sense to me

```
 <ProductWrapper className="col-9 mx-auto col-md-6 col-lg-3  my-3">
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/ have you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the row contains only `ProductWrapper`, it is one column because you have used `col-9.

---

`col-*` classes apply to every device and viewport, from **xs** to **xl**. So if you want to have `2` columns on small size screen, just use `col-6`.

Now since you are using `col-6`, remove `col-md-6`. As said, `col-*` applies to all the screen size irrespective of their width.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3  mx-auto my-3 p-5 bg-primary">

    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-3  mx-auto my-3 p-5 bg-danger">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If the sum of columns are `12`, you do not need to use `mx-auto`.

```html
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 my-3 p-5 bg-primary">

      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-3  my-3 p-5 bg-danger">

      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-3  my-3 p-5 bg-primary">

      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-3  my-3 p-5 bg-danger">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

*FYI: Bootstrap 4 has removed `col-xs-*` classes in favour of `col-*` classes. So use `col-*` instead of `col-xs-*`*

---

#### Update

Bootstrap grid is 12 columns based. That is to say a row contains exactly 12 columns.More than that, the columns will stack no matter the viewport.

If you want to have 12 columns in a row, you use 12 `col-1`. If you want to have 4 same-size columns, you use **4** **`col-3`** since **`4*3 = 12`**. Likewise if you want to have **2** same-size column, you  use **`2`** **`col-6`**

For more info, visit [Bootstrap grid examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/grid/)

Comment: Thank you very much. But why does changing this to 6 make it appear as two columns on small screens?

Comment: This is the width? so by decreasing it it flexes to the size of the screen?